# "I have been talking" vs "I was talking"

Tags: grammar, past-continuous, past-perfect-continuous

May you explain me with some clear examples, what is the difference between using "I have been talking" vs "I was talking"?

I heard this sentence during an interview when he was talking about his past, but couldn't get his mean:

"I have been questioning my mom ...."

Answer (score 2):

The speaker's *meaning* was that he has recently spent time asking his mother questions, maybe on more than one occasion.

> I've been talking to my friends about what we want to do when we leave school. (There have probably been several conversations on the subject.)
>
> I was talking to John yesterday and he told me something I didn't know. (Refers to one particular conversation.)

Answer (score 2):

I have been talking - the present perfect continuous tense

We use the present perfect continuous tense for an action over a period of time **up to now**. (We can talk about repeated actions)

I was talking - the past continuous tense

We use the past continuous tense to say that we were in the middle of an action **in the past.**